# Is there a way to add an item to index 0 of an SQL populated dropdown box in ASP.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm populating a dropdown box from the asp.net side and I was wondering if there was a way to add an item to index 0?

For instance the dropdown box is populated from an SQL database for States, but I would like to populate the top of the drop down with 'All States' to build a query around that (all states is not a field in the actual database).

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT distinct [State ] AS State_ FROM Data_Import] where state is not null"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Refer to this link - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203424/how-to-add-dropdown-list-default-value/24203502)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in code-behind

```
StatesDropDownList.DataSource = ...;
StatesDropDownList.DataBind();

StatesDropDownList.Items.Insert(0,"All States");
```